# Git merge "Already up to date" but not

Tags: git, merge

I messed up a bit. 
I am working on a project, It has many different branches. 
I merged branch A to master, there was some conflict. I messed up here, I did not look into the conflict properly and removed the arrows and then commit then push into master. But It the current master branch does not have the changes I have made on the Branch A. I tried again to merge branch A into master again, but it says "Already upto date".

How do I merge into master again ?

Comment: Post a snapshot of `gitk -all`, with what you want merged to master.

Comment: Git merges changes not yet applied by finding a common base. If you've already made a merge, but this merge just ignored some or all of the changes in the source branch, any attempt at doing another merge on top won't succeed because according to Git, you've already merged those changes. The fact that those changes didn't survive the merge is not something Git cares about. You decided to get rid of those changes, Git shouldn't try to bring them back.

Answer (score 3):

What you have is something like

```
x --- x --- x --- M <--(master)
 \               /
   x --- x --- B <--(branch)
```

Because `M` has `B` as one of its parents, any attempt to merge `B` to `M` (or `master` which is at `M`, or any commit that can reach `M` via chain of parents) will say "already up to date" because it believes `M` is telling how to account for the changes in `B`.  So you need to first undo `M`.

If you've pushed to a remote that is shared with other developers, this is going to cause a headache.  See "Recovering from upstream rebase" in the `git rebase` documentation; even though we're not going to do any rebases, the same situation applies because we're replacing history.

Anyway, here's how, assuming nothing has been added to `master` since the merge:

```
git checkout master
git reset --hard master^
```

Now `M` is no longer reachable by `master`, so you can repeat the merge to properly resolve conflicts.

```
git merge branch
```

Now you'll have

```
                    M
                   /
x --- x --- x --- M' <--(master)
 \               /
   x --- x --- B <--(branch)
```

Note that `M` still exists (though you won't see it by default), and the new merge has a new ID (so I've noted it as `M'`).  Because of this, if you push to a remote (that had already had `M` pushed to it), you have to do

```
git push -f
```

and at this point anyone else using the repository must recover, because you've effectively inflicted an upstream rebase on them.

And if other work had been committed to master after the merge?

```
x --- x --- x --- M --- A --- R --- G <--(master)
 \               /
   x --- x --- B <--(branch)
```

Well, it can still be done, but with more potential trouble.

```
git branch new_master M^
git checkout new_master
git merge branch
```

resolve conflicts, and you have

```
              ------------------------- M --- A --- R --- G <--(master)
             /                         /
x --- x --- x --- M` <--(new_master)  /
 \               /                   /
   x --- x --- B --------------------
               |
            (branch)
```

So now

```
git rebase --onto new_master M master
```

which potentially will have conflicts due to `A`, `R`, and `G` having originally been applied to a different work tree.  If you can sort it out, you then

```
git branch -d new_master
```

resulting in

```
x --- x --- x --- M' --- A' --- R' --- G' <--(master)
 \               /
   x --- x --- B <--(branch)
```

Again the old `M`, `A`, `R`, and `G` commits still exist (and in fact if you'd previously pushed, `origin/master` refers to them; so again `push -f` would be necessary) - but I've removed them from this last diagram because it would get messy.

Answer (score 0):

Easiest/most elegant thing to do? Just go back in history and try the merge again and do this correctly this time. That should be enough. Just in case, "Already up to date" doesn't mean that "*content* from that other branch is fully merged". What git analyses to tell you that is if the *revision* you are trying to merge is already part of the history of your current branch. Given that it is, at least according to your explanation, then git will say something like "well... if that's already merged, then there's nothing else to merge from there".

Comment: Thanks, but i have had merged other branch as well after that conflict, will that be affected ?

Comment: By choosing to go back in history, yes, you'd have to redo those merges.

Answer (score 0):

When you merge two branches using the command `git checkout master` and `git merge develop`, this will make master and develop share the commit trace.

I finally found that solution by checking the documentation at https://git-scm.com/docs/git-merge and I discover that the two branches are merged using the fast forward option, so if you want to keep both branches separated and merge as a commit with the name "Merge develop into master", I suggest to use this command:

```
git checkout master
git merge --commit --no-ff develop
```

You can add the option `--no-edit`, so git will not ask you a message content in the merge commit.